# URL dinamico para una aplicacion web

Tags: java

Tengo una aplicación web que esta a punto de subirse a producción en mi empresa, y manejo url's como la siguiente:

```
http://170.70.141.252:8080/sisalbm/admin/dashboard.jsp
```

Donde indico la ip de mi maquina y el puerto de conexión (Glassfish), sin embargo el área de servidores de mi empresa, me comenta que es una mala practica la forma en que mapeo mi aplicación y que la tengo que corregir, ya que ellos van a montar mi aplicación en 2 servidores en cluster, cuyo caso podría complicar la lógica de mi aplicación.

Manejaba la siguiente sentencia en Java, para mapear las rutas:

```
private static final String servidor = "http://170.70.141.252:8085/";
```

¿Qué tengo que realizar para que las url's de mi aplicación sean dinámicas, es decir no dependan del servidor en el que se encuentra montado?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con una url dinámica? ¿Será que lo que necesitas es un dominio como `www.misitioweb.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente es una mala práctica poner un literal como `path` de una url.

No se si usas un framework pero deberías mirar el método:

```
ServletContext.getContextPath()
```

Que debería devolver:

```
"http://170.70.141.252:8080/sisalbm"
```

Y en las vistas algo como esto, por ejemplo para el action de un formulario

```
action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/dashboard.jsp"
```

Con esto obtendras la direccion "raiz" de tu aplicación independientemente de donde se despiegue.

Hay otros métodos mas específicos del `ServletContext` según la url que quieras obtener.

Answer (score 0):

Para no depender de una url en "duro" apoyate de Context Path, depende de que tecnologías uses para web(JSF, JSP, etc), un ejemplo con JSTL:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<body>

<!-- OBtiene context path con JSTL -->

<c:out value="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}" />

</body>
</html>
```

Salida:

/JSTLExample

Comment: Por la URL que ha adjuntado usa tecnología JPG